# Xslt Dropdown by using xml (using nested for each)

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, web, drop-down-menu

Hi I am new for xslt and I have trouble make dropdown menu navigation , please any can help me I create a static drop down in xslt but I want make drop down as per my XML , In XML there have MenuItem/Menu/Link which I want to make drop down .

**Following is my XML code :**

```
  "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>\r\n \
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='menu.xsl'?>\r\n \
<MenuData>\r\n \
    <MenuTab>\r\n \
        <Tab URL='?do=userMgmt&amp;Page=userMgmt&amp;action=list' Rel='1' TabName='User Management'/>\r\n \
        <Tab URL='?do=clientMgmt&amp;Page=clientMgmt&amp;action=list'  Rel='2' TabName='Client Management'/>\r\n \
        <Tab URL='?do=clientserverMgmt&amp;Page=clientserverMgmt&amp;action=list' Rel='3' TabName='Client ServerManagement'/>\r\n \
        <Tab URL='?do=licMgmt&amp;Page=licMgmt&amp;action=list' Rel='4' TabName='License Management'/>\r\n \
        <Tab URL='?do=serviceMgmt&amp;Page=serviceMgmt&amp;action=list'  Rel='5' TabName='Service Management'/>\r\n \
        <Tab URL='?do=reports&amp;Page=Reports&amp;action=list' Rel='6' TabName='Report'/>\r\n \
    </MenuTab>\r\n \
    <MenuItem>\r\n \
        <Menu Rel='1'>\r\n \
            <Link URL='?do=userMgmt&amp;Page=users&amp;action=list' LinkName='Users' Permission='VW,AD,ED,DL'/>\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=userMgmt&amp;Page=users&amp;action=add'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=userMgmt&amp;Page=users&amp;action=edit'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=userMgmt&amp;Page=users&amp;action=delete'  />\r\n   \
            <Link URL='?do=userMgmt&amp;Page=roles&amp;action=list' LinkName='Roles' Permission='VW,AD,ED,DL'/>\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=userMgmt&amp;Page=roles&amp;action=add'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=userMgmt&amp;Page=roles&amp;action=edit'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=userMgmt&amp;Page=roles&amp;action=delete'  />\r\n   \
        </Menu>\r\n \
        <Menu Rel='2'>\r\n \
            <Link URL='?do=clientMgmt&amp;Page=clients&amp;action=list' LinkName='Clients' Permission='VW,AD,ED,DL'/>\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=clientMgmt&amp;Page=clients&amp;action=add'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=clientMgmt&amp;Page=clients&amp;action=edit'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=clientMgmt&amp;Page=clients&amp;action=delete'  />\r\n   \
        </Menu>\r\n \
        <Menu Rel='3'>\r\n \
            <Link URL='?do=clientserverMgmt&amp;Page=clientServer&amp;action=list' LinkName='Servers' Permission='VW,AD,ED,DL'/>\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=clientserverMgmt&amp;Page=clientServer&amp;action=add'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=clientserverMgmt&amp;Page=clientServer&amp;action=edit'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=clientserverMgmt&amp;Page=clientServer&amp;action=delete'  /> \r\n \
        </Menu>\r\n \
        <Menu Rel='4'>\r\n \
            <Link URL='?do=licMgmt&amp;Page=licDetail&amp;action=list' LinkName='License Details' Permission='VW,AD,ED,DL'/>\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=licMgmt&amp;Page=licDetail&amp;action=add'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=licMgmt&amp;Page=licDetail&amp;action=edit'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=licMgmt&amp;Page=licDetail&amp;action=delete'  />\r\n  \
            <Link URL='?do=licMgmt&amp;Page=licReq&amp;action=list' LinkName='License Request' Permission='VW,AD,ED,DL'/>\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=licMgmt&amp;Page=licReq&amp;action=add'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=licMgmt&amp;Page=licReq&amp;action=edit'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=licMgmt&amp;Page=licReq&amp;action=delete'  />\r\n  \
        </Menu>\r\n \
        <Menu Rel='5'>\r\n \
            <Link URL='?do=serviceMgmt&amp;Page=service&amp;action=list' LinkName='Services' Permission='VW,AD,DL'/>\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=serviceMgmt&amp;Page=service&amp;action=add'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=serviceMgmt&amp;Page=service&amp;action=delete'  />\r\n   \
        </Menu>\r\n \
        <Menu Rel='6'>\r\n \
            <Link URL='?do=reports&amp;Page=Reports&amp;action=list' LinkName='Reports' Permission='VW'/>\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=reports&amp;Page=Reports&amp;action=add'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=reports&amp;Page=Reports&amp;action=edit'  />\r\n \
            <SubLink URL='?do=reports&amp;Page=Reports&amp;action=delete'  />\r\n   \
        </Menu>\r\n \
    </MenuItem>\r\n \
</MenuData>\r\n "
```

**Following is my xslt with static drop down but I want dynamic as per as XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" />
     <xsl:template match="MenuData">
         <ul>
         <xsl:for-each select="MenuTab/Tab">
             <li onclick='toggleNavSelected(this);'><a href="{@URL}" rel="{@Rel}"><span><xsl:value-of select="@TabName"/></span></a>

                <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#123">Tab1</a>

            </div>


            </li>
         </xsl:for-each>
         </ul>
     </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think this is a bit much for one question - try to build a dynamic dropdown by hand in html/javascript and then try to build an xslt to generate one. You might have a look e.g. at [jquery UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) which AFAIK allows things like dropdown

Comment: @StefanHegny thanks for reply , Statically I did but I have problem when I make it dynamic as per XML <Link> , Some tabs have dropdown and some have not , I am beginner, please help how I can do that .

Comment: not completely sure I understand it. What exactly do you mean by "dynamically"? So that it opens when you click? How would you program it by hand? (You probably wouldn't - you should have a look at the jquery link or the [menu widget](https://jqueryui.com/menu/)) Once you have an idea how the html/javascript should look like and function, then we also will get the xslt working.

Comment: @StefanHegny : Please see my xslt code there you can see a div which is inside in <li> , <li> making menu tabs and div make a static dropdown with value tab1 but I want make it value of <Link> tag in xml .

Comment: I see, but then, what do you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: @StefanHegny : dynamic means fetch values from xml in for-each loop not give any static values to href or <a> tab see in xslt code there I have put static values <a href=="#123"> tab1</a>, (#123 and tab1 are static ) So I want fill these values dynamically from xml .I hope you got it.

Comment: and what would be the concrete values in your sample? No #123 or tab1 in the input xml there..., so how should I help you filling them??